# IntelliJIdea: red line on a code snippet with error "cannot access org.codehaus.jackson.ObjectCodec"

Tags: json, intellij-idea, java-8, objectmapper

Preface:

> API method (`import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;`)
>
> ```
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
> public <T> T readValue(JsonParser jp, Class<T> valueType) throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
> {
>     // !!! TODO
>     //  _setupClassLoaderForDeserialization(valueType);
>     return (T) _readValue(copyDeserializationConfig(), jp, _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
> }
> ```

The `ObjectMapper` class has the `readValue` method above.

My custom class method (below) is working fine with no errors, but I see a "red Line" for the code line `mapper.readValue(UserJson, in IntelliJ Idea...`

```
private User serializeFromJsonString(String UserJson) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(UserJson, User.class);
}
```

An example with photo:

[image: intelliJ Idea red line_error]

Comment: So I assume you code compiles fine on the command line? You could try a rebuild with clean cache in IntelliJ (File -> Invalidate caches).

Comment: Your call assumes a `readValue(String, Class<T>)` method signature. So it doesn't match with the `readValue` in your question. The `ObjectCodec` class could be indirectly referenced by `ObjectMapper`. Maybe you miss a dependency. How did you specify your jackson dependencies?

Comment: Thank you both for tying to help me. @SteffenHarbich, sorry I posed a wrong API method here, Here is the actual method, it accepts String..       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)
        throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
    {
     // !!! TODO
//     _setupClassLoaderForDeserialization(valueType);
        return (T) _readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createJsonParser(content), _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Stephan, LazerBass.. the "(File -> Invalidate caches)" didn't seem to work, I already tried it yesterday before I posted this Qn in stackOverflow.

The error didn't appear today.. Seems IDE overlooked into my dependencies..

Below dependency version is hardcoded in my Spring-boot application.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

When I load a Maven project into IntelliJ Idea, it will ask to manually import the dependencies and for this "ObjectMapper" class, the IDE imported a 1.9.12 version of jackson-mapper-asl(in theory it has to take my 1.9.4 version hardcoded in my project). So I went and add additional 1.9.4 jar which is irrelevant, but just thought to check.

I did some more research and checked the "readValue" method of ObjectMapper class in all the versions(link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl) and surprisingly all the versions of this jackson-mapper-asl jar has this method in it.

Narrowing down, the issue seems to be with intelliJ Idea, ref: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207108385-IntelliJ-not-able-to-resolve-classes-of-external-Libraries-for-Maven-projects